# How to get the id from the path parameter of an HTTP request in Cloud Functions (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently developing a serverless application with GCP Cloud Functions (nodejs).
In the following code, I am able to separate the behavior depending on the method of the request, but
I don't know how to get the id of the path parameter.

For example, if I want to retrieve one user, the path would be /users/:id.
I want to retrieve the id in the path and search the DB, but I am stuck because I cannot retrieve the id. (PUT and DELETE too)
Does anyone know anything about this?

I thought I could get it with req.params.id, but I guess not....

```
import type {HttpFunction} from '@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/functions';

export const httpServer: HttpFunction = (req, res) => {
  const path = req.path;
  switch(path) {
    case '/users' :
      handleUsers(req, res);
      break;
    default: 
      res.status(200).send('Server is working');
  }
};

const handleUsers: HttpFunction = (req, res) => {

  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    res.status(200).send('Listing users...');
  } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
    res.status(201).send('Creating User...')
  } else if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    res.status(201).send('Updating User...')
  } else if (req.method === 'DELETE') {
    res.status(201).send('Delating User...')
  } else {
    res.status(404);
  }
}


export const helloWorld: HttpFunction = (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World');
};
```

There is one more problem.

For example, handleUsers will not be called if the path is "/users/1" in the current swich statement. So we want to solve that too.

Furthermore, in the future, there may be paths like "/users/1/hogehoge" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Express [`params`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.params) property of the `request`, but you have to note the following option detailed in the doc: When a regular expression is used for the route definition, "the capture groups are provided in the array using `req.params[n]`, where `n` is the nth capture group".

So the following should work:

`req.params[0]`

---

`req.params` actually returns `{ '0': '...' }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
When I look at req.params[0], it returns 'users/1'.
Is there any way to get just the id part of this?
For example, when I use Express router, I can get the id from req.params.id, and I want to do the same.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to use `str.split('/')` and take the second element of the returned Array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was able to get an ID that way.

However, there is another problem.

For example, if the path is "/users/1" in the current swich statement, handleUsers will not be called. So we want to solve that too.

In addition, there may be a path like '/users/1/hogehoge' in the future….

Comment: You may ask a new question with this new details. Add as much details as possible, in particular the exact paths. You may accept and upvote this answer if it solved your initial problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'll close this question for now.